# What lubricant does Sony use for the PS3 analog stick?

Tags: ps3, controllers

My warranty has expired on my controllers, and I'm looking to take them apart and replace the lubricant since they are sticking/squeaky. I would like to use the best lubricant for this which is why I'm wondering what lubricant Sony uses?

Comment: On mobile so can't easily link but you could check the Home Improvement SE. Silicon lubricant is often recommended for plastic on plastic. (I defer to white lithium grease when metal is involved e.g. hinges.) I'm not sure about this specific application however.

Comment: It might just be plastic dust between the parts as well and not actually a lubricant issue.

Answer (score 2):

For my ps2 controllers I used rubbing alcohol to fix that issue. They both work great and I have had the same system and controllers since 1998.(Still use today)

Comment: I don't know how you've had the same PS2 controller since 1998, when the console released in 2000. Perhaps you mean PS1 controller?

Answer (score 0):

I just used one similar to WD-40 and the results are fantastic.

Just spray a single quick shot on the top of the stick (make sure it reaches the internals), and wiggle it in circular directions for a minute.

I also used a dust-remover spray to remove lubricant excess...let it sit for 5 minutes to "dry" and that's it!

All functional again!
Give it a try!